# How do I setup a build for a particular environment in TFS

Tags: tfsbuild

We have a large web application that uses TFS 2012 to continuously run unit tests, bdd tests and produce a generic build. Our environments (UAT, Pre-Prod etc..) are situated in a dmz with limited access to our dev infrastructure except we can invoke a powershell script which queries the TFS server and fetches the generic build. I then go and modify the configs for the relevant environment which is a repetitive and error prone task.

Our web app has multiple config files for which I am using Slow Cheetah to create environment specific transforms eg. ConnectionsStrings.UAT.Config etc.. What I would like is to set a build quality in TFS which would pass an argument /p:EnviroTarget="UAT" to MSBuild and apply the appropriate transform resulting in a environment specific build which is tagged appropriately. I have the transform working for my local machine where I manually specify which EnviroTarget (and there which config transforms to apply).

My question is how do I can I invoke MSBuild to create a new build based on a change in Build Quality so these builds can created on the CI server independant of developer workstations?

Is this sort of thing possible? I'm aware of a project called TFSDeployer which I had planned to look at - however if needs to run as an agent then it must be able to communicate with TFS from all environments at all times - which seems to be a difficult hurdle for our network. The easier choice (in my opinion) would be to pull in the latest UAT build on the UAT server over powershell.

Hope I made sense here :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio 2012 and web projects, you can publish build for different environments using config transform.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures3PublishingImprovementsChainedConfigTransformsAndDeployingASPNETAppsFromTheCommandLine.aspx

Use publish profile to build different environments into different folder. Then write power shell script to fetch the build and update your UAT or other environment.